# Counting identical values in two arrays

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, counting

> given two arrays of integers A and B of size m, with values in the
>   range [-n,n]. I want an algorithm to count how many common values are
>   in A and B , if a value is repeated we only count it once , for
>   example : A={2,2,14,3} and B={1,2,14,14,5} the algorithm should return
>   2 . Problem is I need to do this in O(m) time.

My attempt was to create an array C, of size 2n. and increment all the values of A and B by n, and count the values of A like: C[A[i]]=1 that would take me O(m) time , and O(1) time to create the array. then going over B and counting how many 1′s I encounter in C.

So far it sounds good, however I have no idea what's in C in the first place and it could be that there's a 1 in there already and that would increment the counter falsely , and initializing C would take O(n) time.

Any ideas? Thanks ahead.

edit: I got an answer so I'll post it here:

1. create an array C of size 2n
2. for i=1 to m: C[A[i]]=0
3. for i=1 to m: C[B[i]]=1
4. initialize a counter : counter = 0
5. for i=1 to m: if C[A[i]]=1 then counter++ and C[A[i]]=2
6. return counter

that way C[A[i]] will only be 1 if while going over B we had to visit there too so we're totally in control of all the array slots we actually need to visit even without initializing it at first to 0 or something.
And when checking again if any of the C[A[i]]'s is 1 : if it is, to avoid going back there and seeing a 1 again we increment it to 2.

overall that's O(m) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize all values in C to be 0. After that your approach is this from what I got from your statement:

1. Maintain a count variable and initialize it to 0.
2. For every integer x in array A, set C[x] = 1
3. Then for every integer y in array B, if C[x] is 1, increment your count variable.

This would give you time complexity of **O(n)** but space complexity would be **O(n)** because you have to initialize every value in C, which is extremely inefficient.

To fix that, use a *hash-map* or a *hash-set* instead of an array. Using a hash-map wouldn't require you to make any modifications to your existing code but using a hash-set is more proper to use here(and more space efficient). They would give you space complexity for **O(m)** while keeping time complexity same.

Also, if you want to do it on **O(1)** space and modification of arrays is allowed, one approach is to sort the arrays and then use a 2 pointer approach that works in **O(m lg(m))**.

Comment: But how would you achieve O(m) time complexity? That only gives O(n) this is why I avoided initializing the array in the first place , but I don’t know what’s in the memory so there could possibly a 1 there and that’s an issue

Comment: @sadElephent Iterating over a hash-map/set in O(m) time because it only stores the values inserted in it, not the whole range. Suppose I have the keys 1 and 100. If I want to use these in an array, I would need to create and array of size 100, but the hash-map or hash-set would be of just size 2 for these 2 keys.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was make a function that receives 2 int arrays and returns how many common values there are.

*(This might not be the most optimized approach but it was never specified it had to be)*

So here's how I did it:

1. Made a function that returns an array with no duplicates.
2. create 2 local int arrays that will hold the given arrays without duplicates.
3. nested loop trough both local arrays and check if they have a common value, and then increment the counter if true

I hope this gave you some new ideas

Comment: Isn’t that O(m²)? That doesn’t meet the time complexity requirement

Comment: yeah you're correct, I actually had no clue what time complexity was, so after some research on this topic I thought of perhaps using a recursive function could give better results perhaps?

Comment: Actually the way to go would be , using the array C of size 2n and:                                                                        2. go over A from 1 to m , and do C[A[i]]=0                                                        3. go over B from 1 to m , and do C[B[i]]=1                                                        4. create a counter and initialize it with 0, and again from 1 to m: if C[A[i]]=1 then counter ++ and C[A[i]]=2                                                                            5. return counter

Comment: I just recreated what you said you did.
 And I changed C[A[i]] = 1; and after that i did C[B[i]] += 1;
Then i checked if any values are above 1 and then increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash set instead of an array. It will be O(m) with less fuss.

The only advantage using an array as you describe has over a hash table implementation is that the array version may use less space, but if space is not an issue the hash set version is much clearer as this is the sort of thing hash sets are intended to be used for.